# How to make plugin for Xcode6

Tags: ios, xcode6, clang

I want to make plugin for Xcode6 but i don't know how to start and make that.Any one please share any link that explains this in detail for Xcode 6? I find for Xcode 4 but that method is not working for xcode6

Comment: i think this link is helpful for you  http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/creating-an-xcode4-plugin/

Comment: @Ilesh Yes, I find this link but the changes of build settings there mentioned are not for xcode6

Answer (score 2):

I am the creator of [IntelliPaste for Xcode](https://github.com/RobertGummesson/IntelliPaste-for-XCode).

Plugin development for Xcode is fun but will also be hard at times. There is no documentation that can be found, at least not from Apple. A lot is guess work and look at how other people's plugins are made.

To get started, I would recommend using [this template](https://github.com/kattrali/Xcode-Plugin-Template). I haven't used it myself but I wished something like that was around when I got started.